# Is NERIS Type Explorer unscientific?

Tags: personality, test, big-five

Why do people call the NERIS Type Explorer of www.16personalities.com unscientific?

According to https://www.16personalities.com/articles/reliability-and-validity it provides good test-re-testing reliability, an internal consistence and discriminant validity.

- If it this is true, what's the difference to big5?
- Is there a fundamental difference to big5 or is the only difference that NERIS Type Explorer has not been approved by scientists yet?